# Protect against React Instances

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'll keep it short. Using Typescript 2.7.2 and ""@types/react": "^16.0.40","

Having really bad problems trying to protect against React Component instances.

consider the component

```
IFooProps {
     element: SomeType
}
...component<IFooProps> {
  ....
  render() {
      return (
          react.cloneElement(element, {onClick: this.myOnClickHandler});
      )
  }
}
```

If element is a react component instance the onClick will be applied to the instance and not run ever. However if its a valid element type I.E div, input, span etc the onClick will get cloned onto the element and run fine.

what type do i replace "SomeType" with to allow JSX elements like div, span, input etc... but not Component instances.

```
<Foo element={<Bar/>} should fail typecheck
<Foo element{<div/>} should pass typecheck
```

iv'e tried ReactNode, ReactElement, ReactHTML, JSX.Element, etc etc etc nothing seems to properally type check it.

Comment: I think this is not possible yet. I might be possible in typescript 2.8. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699

Comment: Actually 2.8 was released on Github yesterday, should not be too long until 2.8 was released on npm

Comment: @paibamboo thanks, what type in typescript 2.8 would you use to type against this? i couldn't see it in the docs.

Comment: Not sure. I hope that it would be `React.ReactElement<IProps>` (which is available but doesn't work as expected now). But they just reopened the issue, and change milestone to 2.9. :(